# Resolve error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, shared-libraries

When i was trying to execute a binary in ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I got this error:

error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Add the shared library?

Comment: How can i find the suitable version. And is there a way to automatically install it by installing some other package that installs the lib?

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu machine nearby to try, but `apt-get install libselinux1` may do it.

Comment: I installed libselinux1 as u said but still getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

This might happen if you have recently installed a shared library and didn't run [ldconfig(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) afterwards. Do `ldconfig`, there's no harm in it.

Comment: Now I found the lib is in the system at '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1' also I did run ' sudo ldconfig -l -p  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1' It showed the lib is in the cache "libselinux.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1"